# Getting an error from save to file : Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java

I'm getting an error when trying to run this program (editing & deleting content in csv file).
Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
    at project.AnimalManager.loadFromFile(AnimalManager.java:88)
    at project.Test.main(Test.java:10)
```

Main App

```
package project;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] ages) {

        //Load file 
        AnimalManager aMgr = new AnimalManager();
        aMgr.loadFromFile("AnimalDetails.txt");

//        try {
//        Animals anim = aMgr.getAnimalById("48331827032019");
//        aMgr.deleteAnimal(anim);
//        } catch (IllegalArgumentException exc) {
//          System.out.println(exc);
//      }

        System.out.println("Edit Animal:");

        boolean edited = aMgr.editAnimal("48331827032019",5,"German","200","Huskies","Huskies","n","n",1000.0,"John"); //By ID
            if (edited) {
                System.out.println("Animal has been edited successfully.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Animal not found (test failed).");

            }
}
}
```

Animal Manager

```
package project;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;





public class AnimalManager {

    private final ArrayList<Animals> animalList;

    public AnimalManager() {
        this.animalList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public boolean addAnimal(Animals a) {
        if (a == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Animal argument is null");

        if(animalList.contains(a))
            return false;
        animalList.add(a);
        return true;
    }

    public void deleteAnimal (Animals a) {
        if (a == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Animal argument is null");

        animalList.remove(a);
    }

    public Animals getAnimalById(String ID) {
        for (Animals a : this.animalList) {
            if (a.getID().equals(ID))
                return a; 
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean editAnimal(String ID, int age, 
            String breed, String breedPurity, String motherBreed, String fatherBreed, String medicalHistory, String identification, double price, String owner) {
        // test for null and for duplicate
        if (ID == null || age == 0 || breed == null || breedPurity == null || motherBreed == null|| fatherBreed == null || medicalHistory == null|| price == 0 || owner == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("One or more arguments are null");

        // Search for the animal.
        for (Animals p: animalList) {
            if (p.getID().equals(ID)) {
                p.setAge(age);
                p.setBreed(breed);
                p.setMother(motherBreed);
                p.setFather(fatherBreed);
                p.setMedical(medicalHistory);
                p.setIdenti(identification);
                p.setPrice(price);
                p.setOwner(owner);
                return true; // Animal has been edited successfully.
            }
        }
        return false; // Means animal with the supplied id is not found.
    }


    //Load from file
    public void loadFromFile(String filename) {
        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));

            sc.useDelimiter("[,\r\n]+");
            //animal details: id,age,breed,purity of breed,mother breed,father breed,medical history, identification, price, owner

            while(sc.hasNext()) {
                String ID = sc.next();
                int age = sc.nextInt();
                String breed = sc.next();
                String breedPurity = sc.next();
                String motherBreed = sc.next();
                String fatherBreed = sc.next();
                String medicalHistory = sc.next();
                String identification = sc.next();
                double price = sc.nextDouble();
                String owner = sc.next();

                animalList.add(new Animals(ID, age, breed, breedPurity, motherBreed, fatherBreed, medicalHistory, identification, price, owner ));

            }
            sc.close();

        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception thrown. " + e);
    }


}

    public void saveToFile(String filename) {

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(); // To store all passengers info.

        for (Animals p : animalList) { // Loop through the passengers to store
            // every passenger as the line of strings to add them to the file.
            output.append(p.getID()).append(",").append(p.getAge()).append(",").append(p.getBreed()).append(",")
                    .append(p.getMother()).append(",").append(p.getFather()).append(",").append(p.getMedical()).append(",")
                    .append(p.getIdenti()).append(",").append(p.getPrice()).append(",").append(p.getOwner()).append("\r\n");
        }

        try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File(filename))) {
            fw.write(output.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Passengers cannot be saved: " + e);
        }

    }

    public String toString() {
        // use String if more comfortable with it - StringBuilding faster for concat
        // than (immutable) String
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (Animals p : this.animalList) {
            strBuilder.append(p.toString()).append("\n");
        }

        return strBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

The idea here is to provide the specific animal ID which you want to edit and write down the new information to replace the old one. I already have the save to file method and I think thats where the issue is coming from.

CSV

```
0,2,AmercianShorthair,100,AmercianShorthair,AmercianShorthair,y,y,900.0,Ann
3,4,GermanShepherd,100,GermanShepherd,GermanShepherd,no,yes,600.0,Dave
6,3,Poodle,100,Poodle,Poodle,yes,no,300.0,Dianna
456,4,Azawakh,50,Unknown,Azawakh,no,no,300.0,April
25041019042018,1,Vizsla,50,Vizsla,TreeingTennesseeBrindle,no,yes,500.0,Lex
3271,1,Beagle,50,Beagle,Unknown,no,no,200.0,Blanton
48331827032019,33,sheperd,50,50,50,no,yes,300.0,Mike
```

Comment: where is line 88 in Animal

Comment: ```double price = sc.nextDouble();```

Comment: You get this exception when the input data of your application doesn't meet its specification. You need to take a look at your input data and fix it.

Comment: instead of double price = sc.nextDouble(), do String price = sc.next(); and print it immedialty after. So you can see what it is.

Comment: changing the price type to String?

Comment: Nevermind i know why

Comment: It was working just fine before, I can edit the content of the csv file, but when I tried running the program again its giving me that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSV should contain commas at the end like so:

```
0,2,AmercianShorthair,100,AmercianShorthair,AmercianShorthair,y,y,900.0,Ann,
3,4,GermanShepherd,100,GermanShepherd,GermanShepherd,no,yes,600.0,Dave,
6,3,Poodle,100,Poodle,Poodle,yes,no,300.0,Dianna,
456,4,Azawakh,50,Unknown,Azawakh,no,no,300.0,April,
25041019042018,1,Vizsla,50,Vizsla,TreeingTennesseeBrindle,no,yes,500.0,Lex,
3271,1,Beagle,50,Beagle,Unknown,no,no,200.0,Blanton,
48331827032019,33,sheperd,50,50,50,no,yes,300.0,Mike
```

Notice the commas at the end of the lines. What is happening, is it is going to the next line immediately and combining the name with the number at the beginning. For example, "Ann3,4" because linebreaks aren't delimiters in this case.

Also in the CSV, you misspelled Shepherd.

Since the delimiter is not new lines, it is the equivalant of this:

```
0,2,AmercianShorthair,100,AmercianShorthair,AmercianShorthair,y,y,900.0,Ann3,4,GermanShepherd,100,GermanShepherd,GermanShepherd,no,yes,600.0,Dave6,3,Poodle,100,Poodle,Poodle,yes,no,300.0,Dianna456,4,Azawakh,50,Unknown,Azawakh,no,no,300.0,April25041019042018,1,Vizsla,50,Vizsla,TreeingTennesseeBrindle,no,yes,500.0,Lex3271,1,Beagle,50,Beagle,Unknown,no,no,200.0,Blanton48331827032019,33,sheperd,50,50,50,no,yes,300.0,Mike
```

Notice how it says 900.0, Ann3, 4, etc. it shifts it all by one so you aren't actually reading in 600.0 as the double, you are reading in Dave as the double.

Edit the code like so:

```
      for (Animals p : animalList) { // Loop through the passengers to store
            // every passenger as the line of strings to add them to the file.
            output.append(p.getID()).append(",").append(p.getAge()).append(",").append(p.getBreed()).append(",")
                    .append(p.getMother()).append(",").append(p.getFather()).append(",").append(p.getMedical()).append(",")
                    .append(p.getIdenti()).append(",").append(p.getPrice()).append(",").append(p.getOwner()).append(",").append("\r\n"); //add another append between getOwner and \r\n
        }
```

Note this is where you are adding animals to the CSV. Here, for each animal, you now append a comma at the end of each line as well. The ed is between appending getOwner and appending the \r\n.

Comment: why is the comma needed at the end of each line?

Comment: Because  there is not delimiter set for the carriage return or newline. You arent reading it as lines. It is as if it is all in one line.

Comment: hmm so what should i do here?

Comment: I deleted the content of the csv file and populate it again with new ones and the program does work. However when I tried to run it again the same error occured

Comment: I edited the code just like u said and also the CSV file, but still find no success.

Comment: Yes. ```double price = sc.nextDouble();```. That is in the ```loadFromFile``` class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190869/discussion-between-justafellowcoder-and-renwid).

Comment: Oh one more thing. Instead of .append many times, you could just .append once and do .append(p.getID() + "," + p.getAge() + "," + p.getBreed() ... ) etc. because you can input a charSequence or String into the .append method.

Answer (score 1):

@JustAFellowCoder has told you a solution to your problem but in my opinion using a CVS file for that is not the best idea.

How about using [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)?
It is very simple and will fix all your problems, you can just do the following:

```
//Your file path
    Path path = Paths.get("Animal.properties");

    //Create a new properties and store it in a file
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    //your id
    int id = 1;
    //Everything in properties must be saved as Strings
    properties.setProperty("Id", String.valueOf(id));
    properties.store(Files.newOutputStream(path), null);

    //new properties
    properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(Files.newInputStream(path));
    System.out.println("Id: " + properties.getProperty("Id"));
```

And you will get a "Animal.properties" file which can be easily restored and a console printing "Id: 1".